# Using a Module in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, module

I'm working on an extension, and am using Princeton's Wordnet database. I want to use code that I found on GitHub (https://github.com/morungos/wordnet) to facilitate my use of the database. I understand the API, but I don't understand how to actually use the files. I downloaded them, and now I just have a folder with the rest of my code. How do i actually implement it in my code? I saw an example in which someone used `require('node-wordnet')`, but some research revealed that this is used in NodeJS (I'm using just JavaScript) to import modules. I tried to figure out how to use modules in JavaScript, but all the resources I found weer incomprehensible (at least by me).

Comment: I think [browserify](http://browserify.org/) is the popular way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks! I'd set yours as right, but you put it as a comment, not answer.